# Nested form tags in angular 2

Tags: angular

Currently I have 2 nested forms.

```
<form [formGroup]="form1">
    <input formControlName="field1" type="text">
    <form [formGroup]="form2">
        <input type="text" formControlName="field2">
        <input type="button">
    </form>
    <input type="button">
</form>
```

I am aware that for nested forms I should have used nested form groups, but I have a special case for this.

If I initialize these forms independently using form builder, will this be allowed in angular 2? 
(I tried for my case and this works, but as HTML 5 prohibits this, will this be a cross browser solution?)

If not I will explain my case for a solution.

Comment: _If I initialize these forms independently using form builder, will this be allowed in angular 2?_
Yes, it works, but as HTML 5 prohibits this, I dont want this thing to work only in my browser and not in others